# How can I cast a wxAuiToolBar from wxControl

Tags: wxpython

I have what I believe to be a wxAuiToolBar pointer (I'm calling it tb):

```
wx.__version__    --> '3.0.2.0'
tb                --> <wx._core.Control; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'wxControl *' at 0x474e600> >

tb.GetClassName() --> u'wxAuiToolBar

tb.__class__ --> <class 'wx._core.Control'>
```

wxPyTypeCast is no longer in wxPython but I'd like to get to the tool buttons.

I got the pointer from the GetChildren() method of the parent frame.

Since python things it's just a control, I can access the toolbar methods.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How did you add buttons to the toolbar? Normally you can keep the reference to each button as class member variable like `self.button1`. So, you will not need to trace back from the toolbar object. here is API https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.lib.agw.aui.auibar.AuiToolBar.html#wx.lib.agw.aui.auibar.AuiToolBar.AddSimpleTool

Comment: @otterb It's actually not my application. I'm doing this in the kicad python interface. I'm hoping to avoid digging through the C++ code to find this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out that if I do:

`import wx.aui`

**Before** I get a pointer to the toolbar, I'll get a pointer of the correct type:

`<wx.aui.AuiToolBar; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'wxAuiToolBar *' at 0x53c0200> >`

If I import after the first access, the pointer will continue to just be of type wxControl. Not a big deal if you know that's how it behaves.